# How do i know i came back from a call intent in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, call

I have an android application in which i am calling call Intent on button click. The sample code for calling the intent is below.

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+phoneNumber));
callIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(callIntent);
```

After the call complete i was returned to the activity from which i called this call intent. Now my question is is there any way i know i returned from a call intent. I am not calling this from activity

Comment: Removing `callIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);` will call 'onActivityResult()' of Activity.

Comment: startActivityForResult(callIntent, requestCodeCode); resultCode can be any integer value, say 0, then override and implement onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data).

Answer (score 1):

To be informed of started activity end, and get results from it you normally should use `startActivityForResult`, then `onActivityResult` will be executed on calling activity.

Comment: 10 seconds faster than me :)

Comment: @marcin_j if i am not calling that from an Activity the also can i use onActivityResult.

Comment: no, startActivityForResult is Activity class method, but you can use it also in fragments.

Comment: But you can always save results in sharedpreferences, and read them in calling Acitivty inside onResume, not sure if this will always work.

Comment: @marcin_j i am calling start activity using context.startActivity(). I am not able to call context.startActivityResult() on top of context.

Comment: This is mechanism to be used from inside of Activity

Comment: @kishore i used startActivityForResult() in `ListView` adapter, using `((MyActivity)getContext()).startActivityForResult()`. But i had to handle result and implement `onActivityResult` within `MyActivity.java`

Answer (score 0):

FirstActivity:

```
public static final REQUEST_CODE = 1; // field

/* # TODO 
   Your intent type instantiation and settings here */
startActivityForResult(callIntent, REQUEST_CODE); // # Calling second activity

@Override
protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
   if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == SecondActivity.RESULT_OK) // # Will inform you if second activity is finished and the result
   {
       // # TODO : Implement your logic here
   }
}
```

SecondActivity; before you call `finish()`:

```
public static final RESULT_OK = 8; // field

// # Set result to OK or define a second flag RESULT_CANCEL = <any number> and set it
setResult(RESULT_OK);
finish();
```